# Estimation of the DoF from a sample of chi2-distributed values

Tags: normal-distribution, estimators, chi-squared-distribution

I have a set of measurements $\{y_j\}_{j=1...Y}$.

$y_j = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2}{N}$

where $N$ is *unkown* and all the $x_{ij}$ are independent normally distributed random variables, with *known* $\sigma$.

- How to estimate $N$?
- What is the variance of the estimate?
- Ideally, what is the probability distribution of the estimator?

---

Here is my best guess.
Since the distribution of $N y / \sigma^2$ is $\chi^2_N$, it follows that $\mathbb{E}y = \sigma^2$ and $\mathbb{V}y = 2 \sigma^4 / N$. Hence I can estimate $N$ as follows

$\hat{N} = \frac{2 \sigma^4 Y}{\sum_{j=1}^Y (y_j - \sigma^2)^2}$

but I have little idea of its variance (especially if $N$ is small)

Comment: What does "$Y$" represent in your formula for $\hat N$?  It appears both as a factor in the numerator and as the upper limit of the sum in the denominator!

Comment: Because it is the number of $y_j$ available

Comment: The denominator divided by $Y$ is an estimate of the $\mathbb{V} y$